# Securing HTTP2 Protocol in Tomcat

Tags: security, tomcat, server, configuration, http2

I have just now configured the HTTP/2 protocol in my Tomcat server, and I need a security review from the community. Do I need to add any other attributes to secure the Tomcat server that allows the HTTP/2 protocol? Below, I have added my connector configurations. Please assist me with this.

```
    <Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxSpareThreads="75" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" name="WebServer" port="8888" redirectPort="443" relaxedQueryChars="\" sendReasonPhrase="true" />


<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" clientAuth="false" connectionTimeout="20000" debug="0" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" keystoreFile="conf/server.p12" keystorePass="****" keystoreType="PKCS12" maxSpareThreads="75" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" name="SSL" port="443" relaxedQueryChars="\" scheme="https" secure="true" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" sslProtocol="TLS" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol">
      <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    </Connector>
```

Comment me If any Misconfiguration is there in the tomcat Server.xml Connector Node?